# WARN with NPE in logs when opening Page Properties on AEM 6.5 and Java 11

Tags: aem, java-11

Running AEM 6.5.3 on Java 11. When I open Page Properties for edition I keep getting from time to time warning in error.log containing NPE thrown from `table_jsp.java:56`:

```
    13.12.2019 07:32:21.487 *WARN* [91.202.100.5 [1576222341248] GET /mnt/overlay/wcm/core/content/sites/properties.html HTTP/1.1] libs.granite.ui.components.coral.foundation.table Failed to wrap datasource for lookahead
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
  at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.coral.foundation.table.table_jsp$LimitIncreaseDatasourceWrapper.<init>(table_jsp.java:56)
  at org.apache.jsp.libs.granite.ui.components.coral.foundation.table.table_jsp._jspService(table_jsp.java:257)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:339) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:97) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:600) [org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp:2.3.6]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.0.56]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:184) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.0.56]
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:491) [org.apache.sling.scripting.core:2.0.56]
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.20]
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.20]
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.20]
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:133) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.106]
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.20]
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:138) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.106]
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.20]
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Thank you for posting. I see this error in AEM 6.4 only after installing Service Package 7 (AEM 6.4.7.0)

Comment: See the article about running AEM 6.5 on Java 11 for more details: https://tech.cognifide.com/blog/2020/aem-on-java-11-with-gradle/

Comment: The system requirements list Java versions as either Supported or Not supported. Java 8 is Supported https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/deploying/introduction/technical-requirements.html

Comment: I have the same issue running  AEM 6.5.4.0 with Java 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment of writing (according to my best knowledge), it is a known issue and it should not cause any problems. It can be fixed by updating `/apps/wcm/core/content/sites/properties/tabs/permissions/items/userGroupList/datasource` node:

```
<userGroupList jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <datasource
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/siteadmin/admin/properties/localacl/localacldatasource"
            itemResourceType="cq/gui/components/siteadmin/admin/properties/localacl/localacllistitem"
            limit="{Long}40"
            page="${empty param.item ? requestPathInfo.suffix : param.item}"/>
</userGroupList>
```

Comment: FYI. Adding the above for closedUserGroupList (not shown) as well as userGroupList (shown above) resolved it in 6.4.7

Answer (score 1):

According to Adobe support this issue is resolved as of AEM 6.5.5.0 though I can't find the hotfix ID that addresses this

Comment: Sadly I have (6.5.5.0) and just got this very error. So its not fixed OOTB.

Comment: The error appears when you open Page Properties in edit mode when using Java 11 with AEM 6.5+.
Since its a known issue and it should be in development, as well as it doesn't break anything, you can just filter it out from the logs in your slinglogger.